# How to retrieve abstract for a DBpedia resource?

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I need to find all DBpedia categories and articles that their abstract include a specific word.
I know how to write a SPARQL query that queries the label like the following:

```
SELECT ?uri ?txt  WHERE {
  ?uri rdfs:label ?txt .
  ?txt bif:contains "Machine" .
}
```

but I have not figured out yet how to search the abstract.
I've tried with the following but it seems not to be correct.

```
SELECT ?uri ?txt  WHERE {
  ?uri owl:abstract ?txt .
  ?txt bif:contains "Machine" .
}
```

How can I retrieve the abstract in order to query its text?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you already know how to search a string for text content, this question is really about how to get the abstract.  If you retrieve any DBpedia resource in a web browser, e.g., http://dbpedia.org/resource/Mount_Monadnock (which will redirect to http://dbpedia.org/page/Mount_Monadnock), you can see the triples of which it's a subject or predicate.  In this case, you'll see that the property is `dbpedia-owl:abstract`.  Thus you can do things like

```
select * where { 
  ?s dbpedia-owl:abstract ?abstract .
  ?abstract bif:contains "Monadnock" .
  filter langMatches(lang(?abstract),"en")
}
limit 10
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20%2a%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20?s%20dbpedia-owl%3aabstract%20?abstract%20.%0D%0A%20%20?abstract%20bif%3acontains%20%22Monadnock%22%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20langMatches%28lang%28?abstract%29,%22en%22%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alimit%2010&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

Instead of visiting the page for the resource, which not endpoints will support, you could have simply retrieved all the triples for the subject, and looked at which ones relate it to its abstract.  Since you know the abstract is a literal, you could even restrict it to triples where the object is a literal, and perhaps with a language that you want.  E.g.,

```
select ?p ?o where { 
  dbpedia:Mount_Monadnock ?p ?o .
  filter ( isLiteral(?o) && langMatches(lang(?o),'en') )
}
```

[SPARQL results](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?default-graph-uri=http://dbpedia.org&query=select%20?p%20?o%20where%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20dbpedia%3aMount_Monadnock%20?p%20?o%20.%0D%0A%20%20filter%20%28%20isLiteral%28?o%29%20&&%20langMatches%28lang%28?o%29,%27en%27%29%20%29%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A&format=text/html&timeout=30000&debug=on)

This also clearly shows that the property you want is http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract.  When you have a live query interface that you can use to pull down arbitrary data, it's very easy to find out what parts of the data you want.  Just pull down *more* than you want at first, and then refine to get just what you want.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of the solutions return what I want. But since it seems you have investigated it throughly, I would like to ask you something more..I did not understand your phrase "which not endpoints will support".. would you like to clarify? It's that I am newbie and I thought I could ask directly DBpedia using Jena for java. I haven't downloaded any dataset. Is my method suitable?Thank you.

Comment: One more question: If you are familiar with Jena framework, I am creating the first query using QueryFactory but an error is returned "Unresolved prefixed name: dbpedia-owl:abstract". Do you know why is that happening? (I might raise a new question for that).

Comment: yeah, you need to define the prefix in your query with `prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology>`. The web interface predefines some for you for convenience, but strictly speaking, they need to be included in the query.

Comment: If the answer worked for you, should should consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).   What I meant about "not all endpoints will support", is that dbpedia is nice in that you can put the URI of a resource into a web browser and get useful information back.  Not all data providers do that for you.  It has nothing to do with the SPARQL side of things.  "endpoint" probably wasn't the best word for me to use there.

Comment: I upvoted the comment by mistake. Actually if I use prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology> nothing is returned when I ask directly the http://dbpedia.org/sparql service, whereas when I ask it  without the prefix it returns a set of results except from the case of Jena where it returns error "Unresolved prefixed name: dbpedia-owl:abstract"

Comment: You need that final `/` on the end (I missed it in my comment): `prefix dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>`.  After, the property is `http://dbpedia.org/ontology/abstract`, not `http://dbpedia.org/ontologyabstract`.  All the prefixes listed at the web interface. Go to http://dbpedia.org/sparql and see the [Namespace prefixes](http://dbpedia.org/sparql?nsdecl) link at the top.  Those are all the prefixes that are automatically used when you use the web interface.  From a programmatic query, though, you'll need to include whichever ones you use.

Comment: @svarog yes,  DBpedia changed their set of default prefixes,so some of the old queries need updated prefixes.